# Would knowing Python help with creating iPhone applications?

Tags: python, iphone, ios, objective-c

Here is what the apple site says:

> With Snow Leopard, Mac OS X makes it
>   easy to use scripting languages as
>   full application development tools.
>   Snow Leopard ships with support for
>   the RubyCocoa Bridge and the PyObjC
>   bridge. These two bridges give
>   developers access not only to system
>   APIs, but to Cocoa frameworks such as
>   AppKit and Core Data, enabling you to
>   build fully native Mac OS X
>   applications in Ruby or Python. The
>   RubyCocoa and PyObjC bridges allow you
>   to freely mix code written in
>   Objective-C with code written in the
>   scripting language. You can quickly
>   build prototypes and then optimise by
>   implementing performance-critical
>   pieces in Objective-C.

How could Python help in this case?

Comment: Knowing Python (among other relatively unique languages) would help with being a better programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are already familiar with Python, it could avoid the need of learning the complexities of Objective C - you would just need to learn enough to wrap the Python.

It is generally thought to be true that working in languages like Python is more productive than doing similar things in C-style languages - so you *may* be able to develop faster and meet your customers needs more quickly.

I'd look at [this](http://www.saurik.com/id/5) website for information on how to develop iPhone applications in Python - since Apple don't actually support this themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Python's a great language, but I do not think it is worth it to try to learn the Python language *and* iPhone programming simultaneously. CocoaTouch has a learning curve and 90+% of the material on programming iOS is going to assume Obj-C. There's a *little* out there for MonoTouch (C#).

I think the problem is that if you read a Python book you're going to get one set of explanations about primitive types (strings, for instance) and memory management and collection classes, but when you program for the iPhone, you're almost certainly going to have to use the native iOS facilities. It's difficult to "mix and match" that sort of stuff when you're learning both sides of the equation.

Having said that, I have a friend who likes Python for programming Android apps, so you aren't entirely locked out of the mobile world! ;-)